# NHibernate.TransientObjectException thrown when saving object in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm having a problem with NHibernate throwing a TransientObjectException when I try to save a customer with an associated list of family names in an MVC 2 project I'm working on.

This is the code for the classes:

```
public class Customer 
{
  public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  public virtual int Version { get; set; } 
  public virtual string Forename { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<FamilyName> FamilyNames { get; set; } 
}
public class FamilyName
{
  public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  public virtual int Version { get; set; } 
  public virtual string Name{ get; set; }
  public virtual bool IsCurrent { get; set; }
  public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Fluent NHibernate for persistence and the mappings look like this:

```
public CustomerMap()
{
  Table("Customers");
  Id(x=>x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
  Version(x => x.Version);
  Map(x => x.Forename).Not.Nullable();
  HasMany(x => x.FamilyNames)
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade.All();
}


public FamilyNameMap()
{
  Table("FamilyNames");
  Id(x=>x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
  Version(x => x.Version);
  Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
  Map(x => x.IsCurrent).Not.Nullable();
  References(x => x.Patient).Not.Nullable();
}
```

I have a strongly-typed EditCustomerDetails view with the following code in it:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SaveChanges", "CustomerDetails")) { %>
<input type="submit" value="Save changes"/>
<%= Html.HiddenFor(customer => customer.Id) %>
<%= Html.HiddenFor(customer => customer.Version) %>
  <label>Forename:</label>
  <%= Html.TextBoxFor(customer => customer.Forename)%>
  <label>Family Names</label>
  <div class="familyNames">
  <%= Html.EditorFor(customer => customer.FamilyNames)%>
  </div>
<% } %>
```

This is the custom editor template for the FamilyName class:

```
<%= Html.HiddenFor(name => name.Id) %>
<%= Html.HiddenFor(name => name.Version) %>
<%= Html.HiddenFor(name => name.Patient.Id) %>
<label>Name:</label>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(name => name.Name) %>
<label>Is Current?:</label>
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(name =>name.IsCurrent) %>
```

Clicking the Save Changes button calls a method on the controller which passes the customer back to a repository which calls the Update method on the ISession. This is where the NHibernate.TransientObjectException is being thrown with the message "object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing".

I have no idea why this is happening. I've stepped into the code and all the data is being passed back correctly from the view with all objects having the correct property values. The only suggestions I've been able to find to fix this make reference to setting Cascade.All in the mapping which is what I was doing anyway.

Any ideas?

Edit: This is the error message:

```
ERROR Shipping.Web.Filters.UnhandledErrorAttribute - An unhandled exception has occurred
 Shipping.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing. Type: Shipping.Domain.Entities.Customer, Entity: Haemoglobinopathy.Domain.Entities.Customer
   at NHibernate.Engine.ForeignKeys.GetEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(String entityName, Object entity, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Type.EntityType.GetIdentifier(Object value, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Type.ManyToOneType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, Boolean[] settable, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement, ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.UpdateOrInsert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Int32[] dirtyFields, Boolean hasDirtyCollection, Object[] oldFields, Object oldVersion, Object obj, Object rowId, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute()
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit()
   at Haemoglobinopathy.Persistence.TransactionAttribute.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) in C:\dev\Projects\Haemoglobinopathy\Haemoglobinopathy.Persistence\TransactionAttribute.cs:line 26
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<>c__DisplayClassf.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<>c__DisplayClassf.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

Comment: This may be related to using actual entities as ViewModels. Your controller will receive an entity that was created by MVC, but wasn't obtained from the Session. It's usually safer to create actual ViewModels and then sync your entities to what you really need to update, not the entire entity (since your view may not be posting back an entire entity).

Comment: I've used ViewModels in the rest of the application but, in this case, the users want a user with admin rights to be able to see and edit the whole record at once so it seemed to make sense to use the actual entities. If I limit the view to just the Customer without the FamilyNames, it updates the record without any problems so I think it must be something to do with the relationship mapping

Comment: Is there any solution you can think of to this without using ViewModels? What would be the advantage to using ViewModels? It seems like a lot of effort (the actual classes are larger than the snippet of code I've posted) and I'm not sure of the benefits

Comment: I see. Well, maybe you can try using Merge() in order to sync up the new object created by MVC. I'm not certain about what it will do with the associations though.

Comment: Which object is it complaining about that is transient?  It's usually helpful to always post the full exception.  Exception.ToString()

Comment: It's saying the customer is transient but when I step into the code, the customer object has the correct guid. I thought nHibernate only treated an object as transient if it had the default value for its Id Type.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling ISession.SaveOrUpdate

Comment: Thanks but I just tried it and it still throws the same exception